# iOS 6 dateFromString returns wrong date

Tags: ios6

I recently upgraded to iOS 6 and have noticed dateFromString is not working correctly, unless I'm doing something wrong with my dateFormat.  It was working prior to the upgrade.

**Code:**

```
NSString *string = @"2012-09-24 - Sun";
NSLog(@"string = %@", string);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"];
[df setLocale:locale];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd - EEE"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
```

**Output:**

```
string = 2012-09-24 - Sun
date = 1999-12-26 05:00:00 +0000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the formatters changed specs in iOS 6:

- Formatters in OS X v10.8 and iOS 6.0 use version [tr35-25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).
- Formatters in iOS 5.0-5.1 use version [tr35-19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: any official documentation ?

Comment: @mihirmehta - Yes.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html).

Answer (score 3):

Please check this:

```
NSString *string = @"2012-09-24 - Sun";
NSLog(@"string = %@", string);
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd - EEE"];
NSDate * date = [df dateFromString: string];
NSDate * sourceDate = date;
NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;   
date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:date];
NSLog(@"date = %@", date);
```