# Does iOS 6 support the timezone PHT when trying to use NSDateFormat?

Tags: ios6, timezone, ios5.1

I am having problems with my code and not sure what is wrong with it.

```
NSString* dateFormat1 = @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss V yyyy";
NSString* dateString1 = @"Fri Jul 26 00:00:00 PHT 2013";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat1];
```

My result for iOS5.1:

```
2013-08-02 11:59:08.459 MySandbox[41502:c07] 2013-07-25 16:00:00 +0000
```

For iOS 6.0

```
2013-08-02 12:02:37.454 MySandbox[41581:c07] (null)
```

*Note, I used V, instead of zzz or Z because it still is null.
*Note 2, I tried to change PHT to PST and it worked. Changed it to JST, it didn't work.

I am guessing that I am not using the correct format. Not really sure which I should use.

*Note 3, as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12564235/ios-6-datefromstring-returns-wrong-date), there really was a change in iOS5 and iOS6 so I guess that is the reason why iOS5 worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [these docs from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html), `NSDateFormatter` uses the Unicode date format patterns, which are part of "Unicode Technical Standard #35".  This standard is evolving, and iOS 5 uses [version 19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns) while iOS 6 uses [version 25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

You can read about the supported values for the time zone in "Appendix J: Time Zone Display Names" ([version 19](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Time_Zone_Fallback) or [version 25](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Time_Zone_Fallback)).

I am not exactly sure why `PHT` was supported before and not it isn't.  But in general, the best advice I can give is to avoid using time zone abbreviations.  While `PHT` is unique, there are many other abbreviations that are ambiguous.  [See the list here](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/).

Instead, you should uses the IANA time zone name whenever possible. (The tr-35 standard calls this the "Golden Zone").  In your case, it would be `Asia/Manila`.  [You can find a full list here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  I am not an Objective C developer, so I'm not sure exactly how you would use this in your input string.  You can try the `VVVV` format specifier, but I'm not sure if it directly accepts the IANA name or not.

You might want to check the results from `[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]` as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871816/634824).  In that post, it does show `PHT = "Asia/Manila"`, but I assume by the date that it was posted that these were generated from iOS 5.